# Spring boot test: spring properties are ignored

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm dealing with a strange issue while running a springboottest.

My properties file is located in `src/test/resources/application.properties`

For some reason, the properties related to h2 db are ignored. All spring namespaced properties are grayed out (other properties are read correctly).

```
# h2
spring.test.database.replace=none
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/devenv/java/h2/database/perscel3_sumo_test;MODE=Oracle;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

My test file:

```
@Import({BatchTestConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class})
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Perscel3SumoBackendTestApplication.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories("be.cm.apps.press.perscel3.repository")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class BatchConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jobLauncherTestUtilsForOptIn")
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("h2.testDataSource")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOptInJob() throws Exception {
        jdbcTemplate.update("delete from cm_members");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
//          jdbcTemplate.update("insert into cm_members values (?, 0, ?, 100000)",
//                  i, "customer" + i);
        }

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();


        Assert.assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

}
```

In the console the following message persists:

```
 Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

This is not what I want.

There are no errors though. I read the properties as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class Perscel3SumoBackendTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Brussels"));
        SpringApplication.run(Perscel3SumoBackendTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the properties file appears in `target/test-classes`.

Point is to get access to the db while debugging, so I want file access instead of in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

Haha well never mind... I overwrote it with a custom datasource bean which I forgot about.
Although source of the problem and the reason why I wrote this bean is an annoying bug in IntelliJ, which claims it cannot find the datasource although it's clearly there.

[image]